# How to connect Linked-serwer using domain user

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

There are 2 mssql servers in the environment: SQL1 and SQL2.
There is a linked server from sql1 to sql2 using the domain user ad1 (ad1 has permission to read databases on SQL1 and SQL2)

There is an app3 server on which the application is installed, and the ad2 application pool account (domain user) connects to the database on SQL1.

I would like to be able to perform database queries from the application level via linked servers on SQL2.
So the question is how to set up a linked server connection to make this operation possible, with only the ad1 user who has permissions to SQL2

Comment: As stated in [Create linked servers (SQL Server Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16):
"There are two strategies to configure here that can be used alone or combined. The first is to map logins from the local server to the remote server, and the second is how the linked server should treat logins that aren't mapped.".

Follow "Add login mappings" to create a direct map from ad2 local login to ad1 remote login.